Make additional "All X" folder groups in Apple Mail for Zoho Mail folders
I recently switched to Zoho Mail for one of my accounts and I decided I want to do it with all of my email accounts.
I noticed however, people would tell me they sent me invites from Websites, and some other things and I would not see these in Apple Mail, nor would I see them in my Zoho Mail inbox.
Well, it turns out that Zoho Mail filters things into different folders - it has a Newsletters folder, and a Notifications folder.
Now these folders ARE ACCESSIBLE with IMAP. And they show up in Apple Mail for the one account. When I switch over to Zoho Mail for all my accounts, it will be the same.. Every account will have a Newsletters folder and a Notifications folder.
I really REALLY like this functionality because it solves the problem of "Your code is XYZABC" mails and newsletters cluttering the inbox.
Problem is, I can't seem to find a way to have all of these custom Zoho folders in an "All XYZ" type fashion in the favorites.
In favorites there is: All Inboxes, All Sent, All Archive, etc. etc. that aggregates those folders from ALL accounts.
But I see no way to add this type of thing.. I can only add ONE folder, such as the Notifications folder in a SPECIFIC account to the favorites. That's not gonna work I don't want to have a ton of favorites.
And I could make a Smart Mailbox and add that to the favorites (I am not sure IF I CAN ... just that I'm thinking it MAY be possible to choose "folder name" as a criteria), but I really like that I can click the arrow next to All Inboxes for example, and select ONLY the account I want, and see ONLY that accounts inbox, without a ton of clicking around.
Really useful. Adding a bunch of favorites for the different Notifications/Newsletter folders in each email account will just clutter up my favorites bar with his already filled up completely.
